# Workbench Moderation: need new update notification

Tags: notifications, workbench

The module Workbench is working great on Drupal 7. I need to **add notes or notify** user to change or update, so I installed the module [Workbench Moderation Notes](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation_notes). The only issue I have with this module is no "New note" notification(see screenshot for detail). Is there a way to add that feature or any module can replace this? Does [Workbench Email](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_email) work better?

[image]

Comment: Did you see if there is an action for this that works with Rules?  Rules integration is somewhat recent with WBM, so you may need to use the DEV version.

Comment: @MPD Workbench Moderation Notes is Dev version and the only one. This module does not have any configuration or permission setting. I also don't see there is a "React on event" option for Workbench on Rules. Do you mean the Dev verison for Workbench moderation? If so, should I install Workbench and workbench access Dev version too?